# Creating a View programmatically according to screen resolution

Tags: java, android, view, size

I created a BaseAdapter that implements ListAdapter. This BaseAdapter reads a JSON file and populate my ListView inflating a custom layout.

In this JSON file I have a boolean value (active = true or active = false). If active is true, I inflate the custom layout and everything is fine, but if active is false, I need to create a new View in this custom layout. Here's my code:

```
if (!active) {
    JSONObject notifications = jsonData.getJSONObject("notifications");
    String message = notifications.getString("message");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.height = 70;

    TextView warning = new TextView(Controller.getContext());
    warning.setText(message);
    warning.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    warning.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    warning.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    warning.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    warning.setLayoutParams(params);

    // contentFrame is a RelativeLayout where the view is created;
    viewHolder.contentFrame.getLayoutParams().height = 320;
    viewHolder.contentFrame.addView(warning);
 }
```

My problem here is this:

```
params.height = 70;
viewHolder.contentFrame.getLayoutParams().height = 320;
```

I'm saying that my TextView is 70 pixels higher and my RelativeLayout is now 320 pixeis high.

It looks nice on my phone, but if I test on a phone with other resolution it will not look the same right?

Is there any way to create a View and define is Height or Width according to the screen resolution? Maybe create the View 10% the size of the screen resolution? Is that a good pratice? What's the best aproach for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to scale your size values according to the screen density:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

That means you have to multiply all size values with `density`:

```
params.height = (int)(70 * density);
viewHolder.contentFrame.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(320 * density);
```

and the same with padding values:

```
warning.setPadding((int)(10 * density), 0, (int)(10 * density), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using hardcoded pixel values, use DPs. DPs account for the device density so views look pretty much the same regardless of which device the app runs on.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence) for additional info.

So, define this in your dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_width">320dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then read it like this:

```
int width =  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_width);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define dimensions in XML [like any other resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), and have those resources automatically selected by Android based on the current device configuration.

So you have two definitions, one for "normal" circumstances, and another for "bigger screen":

```
src/main/res/values/dimens.xml
src/main/res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
```

Each resource file can have the same dimension defined in dp.  Android will pick the appropriate one.  If you need to read the values programmatically as raw pixel sizes, you can do that with [Resources.getDimensionPixelSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize(int)).

I would recommend against trying to define list items in terms of percentage of the size of the screen.